# Date/Time Calendar View for SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar

I have a calendar with a created field of Expired Date/Time.  I want the view to only show items that have not expired.  The Expired Date/Time field is a Date/Time Field.  I tried the filter Expired Date/Time >= [Today].  This didn't work.  Is there a solution that works?

Answer (score 0):

How did you set the filter?

You can provide some screenshots/steps. The screenshots/step will help to reproduce the issue and find the cause of the issue.

Per my testing result, it works.

I set the filter for the view as shown below:

[image]